# how to apply delect functionality in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

hi i have a form in bootstrap which is appending by jquery (by clicking button it opens again and again), i wants when i click on trash icon then it deletes from frontend, screenshot of form which i wants to del by clicking on trash icon

[image]

Bootstrap code:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 create-task-btn1" style="padding-top: 155px;">
      <span class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon appendTest" 
                                                        style="width: 140px; height: 100px; font-size: 20px; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
        <br>
          Assign Task
       </span>
 </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.appendTest').click(function() {
    $('#exampleIdTest').append(`<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 82%; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 350px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            <td rowspan="3">
                                <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
  </div>`);
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code simply changed now working fine. Hope this help you

```js
function remove_item(_this) {
  
  jQuery(_this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove()
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.appendTest').click(function() {
    $('#exampleIdTest').append(`<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 82%; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 350px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            <td rowspan="3">
                                <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" onClick="remove_item(this)" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
  </div>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<div class="col-md-4 create-task-btn1" style="padding-top: 155px;">
  <span class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon appendTest" style="width: 140px; height: 100px; font-size: 20px; padding-top: 15px;">
        
          Assign Task
       </span>
</div>

<div id="exampleIdTest"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some solutions:

1- When clicked on delete button use `parent()` method of jQuery to get to the main parent element of that part and remove it with `remove()`

```
// place this code out of $(document).ready()
$(document).on('click', '.fa.fa-trash-o', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove()    
})
```

2- Give same class or attribute to main parent element of that part and your delete button (consider that the class must be different for every time that append clicked). Now when user clicks on delete button you get the other class and remove it

for example change your code to:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter = 0;
        $('.appendTest').click(function() {     
            $('#exampleIdTest').append(`<div class="container-fluid" partCounter="${counter}" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 82%; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 350px;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                    <td rowspan="3">
                                        <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" partCounter="${counter}"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                    <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div> 
        </div>`);
        counter++
    });
});
```

now add:

```
// place this code out of $(document).ready()
$(document).on('click', '.fa.fa-trash-o', function(){
    $('[partCounter=' + $(this).attr('partCounter') + ']').remove()    
})
```

Comment: its not working plz check the updated question, by clicking the assign task button it opens and by clicking again and again it opens again and again

Comment: everytime you click on `.appendTest` a new part added to your `#exampleIdTest`, and with above codes you can delete that part with clicking on trash icon. If you expect another behavior please explain.

Comment: sorry to say but its still not deleting

Comment: Do you place codes in `$(document).ready()`? you must place them out of it

Comment: It's not working. Check before you update the code.

Comment: @Bhavanaditya Can you tell how you use it? and if you get an error on console please tell

Comment: @Ashkan i wants that when i click on trash icon then it deleted/disappears, but nthing happens and in console no error is showing

Comment: @alphadev I'm going to edit it and upload a full file